# How does inheritance work with kwargs in Python 3?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x, keyword-argument

Considering the following sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

class Parent:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Expect data1, data2
        self.values = kwargs

    # Accessor method to set object values
    def setvalue(self, k, v):
        self.values[k] = v

    # Accessor method to get/return object values
    def getvalue(self, k):
        return self.vlaues.get(k, None)

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Expect data3, data4
        self.values = kwargs

    # Accessor method to set object values
    def setvalue(self, k, v):
        self.values[k] = v

    # Accessor method to get/return object values
    def getvalue(self, k):
        return self.values.get(k, None)

def main():
    new_object = Child(data1 = 'abc', data2 = 'def', 
        data3 = 'ghi', data4 = 'jkl')

    for v in new_object.values:
        print('{}: {}'.format(v, new_object.getvalue(v)))

    new_object.setvalue('data1', 'tuv')
    new_object.setvalue('data4', 'xyz')

    for v in new_object.values:
        print('{}: {}'.format(v, new_object.getvalue(v)))

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

I'm wondering how I can take advantage of the flexibity of `kwargs` while still employing some basic inheritance. In the real application I'm writing, each class actually has many different attributes associated with it.

My concern is that, because `kwargs` are so flexible (and nebulous), I can't maintain the parent-child relationship of my classes -- `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, and `data4` will all get applied to the `Child` class.

How do I ensure that `data1` and `data2` are attributes of the `Parent` superclass, and that `data3` and `data4` are attributes of the `Child` subclass?

I'm trying to design my class structure "the right way" while keeping the code somewhat simple and elegant. Does it even matter? Maybe I'm going down the wrong road on this. Is there a better way to do this?

Sorry if I'm rambling here. Just trying to understand. Thanks in advance for your assistance and patience...

Comment: It doesn't make sense to make the distinction you are making between attributes of the Parent class and attributes of the Child class. The whole point of inheritance - in any language - is that a child *is-a* parent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first problem is that you're not actually creating attributes in the first place. If you want attributes, create attributes. If you want a key-value mapping, create a mapping. What you've created is a special-purpose, limited-functionality mapping with a non-standard API. There's no good reason for that.

If you want to ensure that something is an attribute of something, it has to be an attribute in the first place, which you normally do with `self.spam = eggs` assignments (although in some cases you do it with `setattr` or even `self.__dict__.update`).

---

> How do I ensure that data1 and data2 are attributes of the Parent superclass, and that data3 and data4 are attributes of the Child subclass?

If ensuring that is part of the class's invariants, you want to ensure it explicitly in each class, and pass any remaining arguments up with `super`. For example:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.data1 = kwargs.pop('data1', None)
        self.data2 = kwargs.pop('data2', None)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.data3 = kwargs.pop('data3', None)
        self.data4 = kwargs.pop('data4', None)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

But you may notice that you're not really getting any benefit out of the extra generality here; you can—and probably should— write the same thing like this:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, *, data1=None, data2=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data1 = data1
        self.data2 = data2

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, *, data3=None, data4=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data3 = data3
        self.data4 = data4
```

---

All that being said, I think you're operating from a misapprehension in the first place:

> My concern is that, because kwargs are so flexible (and nebulous), I can't maintain the parent-child relationship of my classes -- data1, data2, data3, and data4 will all get applied to the Child class.

No, none of these attributes are being applied to *either* class. They're being applied to every instance of `Child`—but there's no question as to whether they got those attributes as a `Parent` instance or as a `Child` instance; they got them just by being an object with a `__dict__` and having a `self.spam = eggs` assignment. Whether you look at the instance as a `Parent` or as a `Child`, those attributes are there—as well as random extra attributes that you add long after construction, or standard attributes inherited from `object`, or anything else.

If you really, really want to enforce that `Parent` instances that aren't `Child` instances only have `data` and `data2`, you can do that with `__slots__`, `@property`, explicit descriptors… let's do the first, since it's simplest and clearest here:

```
class Parent:
    __slots__ = ('data1', 'data2')
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.data1 = kwargs.pop('data1', None)
        self.data2 = kwargs.pop('data2', None)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class Child(Parent):
    __slots__ = ('data3', 'data4')
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.data3 = kwargs.pop('data3', None)
        self.data4 = kwargs.pop('data4', None)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Now, any attempt to assign a `data3` attribute on a `Parent` instance will raise an `AttributeError`, unless it's actually an instance of some subclass that adds a `data3` slot, like `Child`.

Comment: @dano: Yes, typo; thanks for catching it, fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough feedback. My primary goal here is to understand the correct approach in creating classes and subclasses (both generally and from a Python perspective); I appreciate it.

Comment: Oh. And yeah... *duh*... I do see the difference between classes and instances of classes. I was kind of out in left field, there.

Comment: @drwtod: I didn't think you were being stupid there, just that you were thinking in more Java or C++ than Python terms. In Python, there's no sensible difference between "attributes I have because of my immediate class" and "attributes I have because of a base class", because attributes (and variables in general) aren't declared anywhere; in Java, on the other hand, there is a real and important difference, because attributes are declared as part of the class definition.